# NullPointerException when I don't access the Button view in my fragment through rootView view

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

Why do I get  NullPointerException when I don't access the Button view in my fragment through rootView view?

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

Button buttonClick =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{     
  @Override 
  public void onClick(View view) 
  {     
    //Do something when button is clicked
  }
});
```

Comment: You are inflating the xml on rootView, is there another way of getting it? are you meaning just calling findViewById() on the activity instead of rootView?

Comment: your code seems ok. verify button id R.id.button in fragment_main.xml

Comment: Have you return rootView ?

Comment: Or show your whole java file code.

Comment: I am just asking that why do we need to specify rootView "rootView.findViewById" to access Button. Can't we just write findViewById  since we want to access button present in the same fragment from where we are calling  findViewById ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findViewById() looks for the requested view on the content of the calling view.

So if you call it from the activity it will look for the view on the contentView you set with setContentView(), thats why its returning null.

You need to call findViewById() on the view that holds the view you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating to the variable rootView, so the only way to get ahold of your button is through your variable.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is precisely as it is, nothing more to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare Button in Fragment

```
Button buttonClick;
```

And then Write below code in Fragment.

```
 buttonClick = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize button onClick() inside the fragment

initialize like this

```
public class Yourclassname extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
  {
    Button button1
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.postpaid, container, false);

    button1 = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
 return rootview;
}
public void onClick(View view) 
 {     
 //Do something when button is clicked
 }
 }
```